# Is There A Way to Repair This?

Tags: cabinets

One side of my kitchen cabinet that typically includes the knob hardware is  missing. I went to Armstrong Cabinets and they no longer carry this cabinet. How do I repair this? Thanks! (I’m experiening difficulty with photo upload)

Comment: Really need a picture...

Comment: Really need a picture...